# lavaan WARNING: model has NOT converged

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm runing a mediational Path analysis as below.

```
pa_med<-'
#measurement model

psychosis =~ worriedPeopleHearMyThoughts+ feelSecretOrgWatching

suicideRisk =~ thoughtsOfSuicide+ fearLoseControlSuicide+ plansForHowSuicide+ betterOffDead

substanceUse =~ othersConcernedDrugUse+drugUseInterferes+needToReduceDrugUse+concernedDrugDependent

#regression

psychosis ~ hurtSelfPurposely

substanceUse ~ hurtSelfPurposely  

Anxiety ~ hurtSelfPurposely

Depression ~ hurtSelfPurposely

suicideRisk ~ psychosis + substanceUse + Anxiety + Depression
'
```

I split the sample into subgroups according to their anxiety levels, such as no anxiety, mild anxiety, moderate anxiety, and severe anxiety. When conducting this mediational model for these groups using Lavaan, I received this message:

```
Warning message:
In lavaan::lavaan(model = pa_med, data = df, group = "levelofAnxiety",  :
  lavaan WARNING: model has NOT converged!*
```

I wonder if it's because I can't split groups by one of the factors in my model. Or I should constraint the loading for factor "Anxiety" across groups.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic because it's about the failure of an algorithm to converge, which is a statistical topic. In particular, OP's problem likely stems from an underidentified model rather than a coding error, which SO will not be able to diagnose.